# IOCP Threads and GetQueuedCompletionStatus

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, sockets, iocp

Been trying to wrap my head around windows IOCP and have run into a few issues as many other people seem to be doing so.

So far what I'm trying to do is run a TCP IOCP server, which creates 3 accept sockets and has a thread for each waiting on a GetQueuedCompletionStatus. Below is the main thread loop for said threads.

The problem I've run into currently - I believe -  is as follow.

1. Spawn 3 "worker" threads
2. Create 3 accept sockets in a loop and call AcceptEx() for each
3. Client 1 connects with no issue on Thread 1
4. GetQueuedCompletionStatus releases Thread 1 to continue on
5. Thread 1 now waits for data on WSARecv().
6. **!!PROBLEM!!** Client one sends data, Thread 1's WSARecv() seems to now send a completion packet
   which is picked up **BY ANOTHER THREAD OUT OF THE 3**
7. Code hangs because of obvious reason (Thread 1 is waiting on the GQCS after its WSARecv(), but never receives it because it went to Thread 2 and Thread 2 is told to continue even though it hasn't actually received a client)

I say I believe this to be the issue because I've run it through debugger and outputted thread id's to console and have seen that right after starting a single client I get 2 outputs of "Accepted client on thread ..." with 2 different thread ids.
Also, when I was stepping through the code in the debugger, as soon as I went passed the WSARecv() in Thread 1, the code hit a breakpoint in Thread 2 at the GQCS line.

I'm clearly misunderstanding something about the use/function of GetQueuedCompletionStatus or something related to it. Is my fundamental methodology here just wrong or is this a easy fix I'm just not getting?

How can I get it such that, the WSARecv() sends its completion packet/signal thing to the write thread?

```
// Initialize Winsock...


// Create a handle for the completion port
hCompPort = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, (u_long)0, 0);
if (hCompPort == NULL) {
    wprintf(L"CreateIoCompletionPort failed with error: %u\n",
        GetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

//Create worker threads
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    threads.push_back(std::thread(WorkerThreadFun));
}

// Create a listening socket
ListenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

// Associate the listening socket with the completion port
u_long ck = 111;
CreateIoCompletionPort((HANDLE)ListenSocket, hCompPort, (u_long)0, 0);

//----------------------------------------
// Bind the listening socket to the local IP address
// and port 27015 


if (bind(ListenSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&service, sizeof(service)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    wprintf(L"bind failed with error: %u\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

//----------------------------------------
// Start listening on the listening socket
iResult = listen(ListenSocket, 100);

printf("Listening on address: %s:%d\n", ip, port);


iResult = WSAIoctl(ListenSocket, SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER,
    &GuidAcceptEx, sizeof(GuidAcceptEx),
    &lpfnAcceptEx, sizeof(lpfnAcceptEx),
    &dwBytes, NULL, NULL);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    wprintf(L"WSAIoctl failed with error: %u\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

//pre-emptively create sockets for connections
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    // Create an accepting socket
    AcceptSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    }
    //create Overlapped struct for AcceptEx and following that GetQueCompStatus
    LPWSAOVERLAPPEDPLUS pOl = new WSAOVERLAPPEDPLUS();

    //Initialise the "extended" overlapped struct with appropriate data
    memset(pOl, 0, sizeof(WSAOVERLAPPEDPLUS));
    pOl->operation = OP_ACCEPTEX;
    pOl->client = AcceptSocket;
    pOl->listenSocket = ListenSocket;

    DWORD expected = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) + 16;
    int buflen = (sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN) + 16) * 2;
    char* pBuf = new char[buflen];
    memset(pBuf, 0, buflen);
    

    // Empty our overlapped structure and accept connections.
    //memset(&olOverlap, 0, sizeof(olOverlap));

    bRetVal = lpfnAcceptEx(ListenSocket, AcceptSocket, pBuf, 
                            0, //0 to avoid waiting to read data from a send()
                            expected, expected, 
                            &pOl->dwBytes, 
                            &pOl->ProviderOverlapped);
    if (bRetVal == FALSE)
    {
        int err = WSAGetLastError();
        if (err != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
        {
            wprintf(L"AcceptEx failed with error: %u\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(AcceptSocket);
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
    }
}//for
```

WorkerThreadFunc()

```
while (TRUE)
{
    bOk = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(hCompPort, &bytes_transferred, (PULONG_PTR)&completion_key, &pOverlapped, INFINITE);
    
    std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
    std::cout << "Accepted client on thread" << this_id << "Going to sleep for 5 seconds" << std::endl;
    //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    if (bOk) {
        // Process a successfully completed I/O request

        if (completion_key == 0) {
            // Safe way to extract the customized structure from pointer 
            // is to use 'CONTAINING_RECORD'. Read more on 'CONTAINING_RECORD'.
            WSAOVERLAPPEDPLUS* pOl = CONTAINING_RECORD(pOverlapped, WSAOVERLAPPEDPLUS, ProviderOverlapped);

            if (pOl->operation == OP_ACCEPTEX)
            {
                if (hCompPort2 == NULL)
                {
                    hCompPort2 = CreateIoCompletionPort((HANDLE)pOl->client, hCompPort, (u_long)&this_id, 0);
                    // hCompPort2 should be hCompPort if this succeeds
                    if (hCompPort2 == NULL)
                    {
                        wprintf(L"CreateIoCompletionPort associate failed with error: %u\n",
                            GetLastError());
                        closesocket(pOl->client);
                        closesocket(pOl->listenSocket);
                        WSACleanup();
                        break;
                    }//if: CreateIOCP error
                }//if: accept socket already IOCP

                // Before doing any WSASend/WSARecv, inherit the 
                // listen socket properties by calling 'setsockopt()'

                setsockopt(pOl->client, SOL_SOCKET, SO_UPDATE_ACCEPT_CONTEXT,
                    (char*)&pOl->listenSocket, sizeof(pOl->listenSocket));


                DWORD& recvbytes = pOl->dwBytes;
                char buf[MAX_BUF];
                WSABUF wsabuf = { MAX_BUF, buf };
                DWORD flags = 0;

                if (WSARecv(pOl->client, &wsabuf, 1, &pOl->dwBytes, &flags, &pOl->ProviderOverlapped, NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    int err = WSAGetLastError();
                    if (err != WSA_IO_PENDING)
                    {
                        printf("WSARecv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                        //return 1;
                    }
                }
                bool qresult = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(hCompPort, &pOl->dwBytes, 
                                                        (PULONG_PTR)&completion_key, &pOverlapped, INFINITE);
                if (!qresult)
                {
                    DWORD err = GetLastError();
                    printf("* error %d getting completion port status!!!\n", err);
                }
                int iResult = WSAGetOverlappedResult(pOl->client, &pOl->ProviderOverlapped, &pOl->dwBytes, FALSE, &flags);
                if (iResult == FALSE) {
                    wprintf(L"WSARecv operation failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                    //return 1;
                    break;
                }
                wsabuf.buf[recvbytes] = '\0';
                std::cout << "Bytes received: " << recvbytes << std::endl;
                std::wcout << "Bytes create: " << wsabuf.buf << std::endl;
            }
            delete pOl;
        }
    }
    else {
        // Handle error ...
    }
}
```

}

Comment: *has a thread for each waiting on a GetQueuedCompletionStatus* you use wrong design. count of threads must not equal to count of sockets. count of threads usual ~= count of cores. every thread simply wait on iocp and call callbacks. *which is picked up BY ANOTHER THREAD* - this is your main error - which tread pop packet is random. must be no any difference

Comment: Yeah I managed to work that out eventually. Thanks anyway